# What does "Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str' mean in my case?

Tags: python, format

This is part of a sort function I defined in a test file -- and it ran fine. Then I transferred it to my main file and I'm getting all sorts of errors, mostly about mixing ints with strs, but also including this "f"-ing one, so to speak. Could this mean that pygame doesn't support the f-string formatting of newer Python versions?

````
table = stat_font.render(
                    f"{teams[team][0]:12}{str(teamstats[team][0]):>2} - {str(teamstats[team][1]):>2} "
                    f"{str(teamstats[team][4]):6.3f}  {str(ptdif):>}", True, white)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what the error message says: You are trying to use the `:6.3f` format specifier on a string, which doesn't support it. Just remove the call to `str` in the f-string field. It is called automatically.